# What is the relationship (if any) between Skøyen and Skøyenåsen in Oslo?

Tags: etymology, toponymy, norway

In Oslo there are two neighbourhoods called Skøyen and Skøyenåsen

"Åsen" means "the hill" or "the ridge", so Skøyenåsen means "The Skøyen Hill".

[image]

Skøyen and Skøyenåsen are not close to each other, though, they are roughly 10 km apart, on opposite sides of the city.

According to [some sources](https://lokalhistoriewiki.no/wiki/Sk%C3%B8yen_(Oslo_gnr_3_og_4)) and Wikipedia, the word "Skøyen" is of unknown etymology. Is this correct, or is there some information somewhere on the etymology?

Do these two places just happen to both share this name, or is there some relationship between them? Did one give rise to the name of the other? Or perhaps they both just share the same etymology?

Answer (score 5):

It was two different farms with the same name ([Bull, *Akers historie*](https://www.nb.no/items/f963709bdb15e750d090f42c7a41b70c?page=0), p. 11).

(The map shows the oldest names, from the Bronze age or earlier.)

[image]

So [Skøyenåsen](https://no.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sk%C3%B8yen%C3%A5sen) belonged to [Nordre Skøyen](https://no.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nordre_Sk%C3%B8yen_hovedg%C3%A5rd) in East Aker.

Comment: Any idea why it was that theses two farms had the same name?

Comment: No but that does not have to be a great mystery. There are quite a few entries for the name in the index of Bull, if you want to dig deeper.